# how can I increment in this code

Tags: c, increment

Write a program that displays a new random permutation of the integers 0 to 9 at the request of its user. For example, the program’s output could be as follows:

Your program should prints how many 7 was printed when user type no.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i , total , r;
    char ans;
    srand(time(NULL));
    do{
        for( i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            r= (rand()%(9-1+1)) + 1;
            printf ("%d ",r);
        }
        total =0;
        if (r==7)    // Here how can I correct this so total will increase every time
        {            // there is a 7 in the string
            total++;
        }
        printf("\nAnother permutation: y/n?\n");
        scanf(" %c",&ans);
        if (ans != 'y')
        {
            printf("Bye!\n");
            printf("The number of 7's is: %d", total);
        }
    }while(ans=='y');
    return 1;
}
```

I have a problem with my code. How can I increment the 7's shown in this program after != 'y'.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: And tell us what your problem is.

Comment: (Oh, I know. The usual `scanf("%c")` - extranewline - whynotterminating" issue...)

Comment: @HishamTAlHammad Better than it is currently. Do you appear to have a space and a newline key on your keyboard?

Comment: you are initializing 'total=0' inside the for loop.What value of 'total' you are getting in last print statement?

Comment: Every time I try something it's either 0 or 1, it never counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `total=0` before entering into the do-while loop, to get the correct `total`.

Comment: Also extend the for-loop to include the `if(r==7)` statement. (My solution assumes you want to calculate the total number of 7's that occurred in all random numbers that were generated)